# Can updates break Ubuntu or damage my hardware?

Tags: updates, security

Is there any need for me to be concerned about updates breaking something in Ubuntu or my hardware or are all the updates stable?

Comment: This is way to broad and open ended to be answerd well here, there is always an need for concern when updating any software, nothing is perfect. A quick google search finds a mountain of information on this https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+risks+of+updating&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b please at least take the time to try google before asking

Comment: I have been updating Ubuntu for over a decade, with exactly zero problems. So **I** think they are stable. However, rare problems with updates **do** occur, so your mileage may vary. Updates are not tested by Ubuntu developers on your exact hardware in your exact configuration with you piloting the rocket, so some minor variations are expected.

Comment: I really see no reason to worry about Damages being caused.

Comment: I did a ton of Googling for this question before I posted it here and could not find anything conclusive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updates from the Ubuntu archive are tested before being released as updates, and are not generally just new versions of things, but backported fixes. However, sometimes things may break for some subsets of users, not because of malice, but simply because computers are extremely complex, and they are not all the same.

Comment: I would add to this that the likelihood of any Ubuntu software component, original or update, damaging hardware is vanishingly small.  As noted, however, if you have a particularly obscure piece of hardware, an update may cause it to stop working until you can either roll back the update or get a newer update that restores support for that component.

Comment: While physical damage is extremely unlikely, it has happened with updates in the past, and not just with Ubuntu. See the recent fiasco with Ubuntu 17.10 on some certain laptops with a certain BIOS.

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback, I really appreciate it.  I did figure out how to selectively install updates, but after all the feedback on my question and some digging into the change logs and descriptions have decided to just roll with all the security updates.  Seems to be fine:)

Answer (score 2):

So, the most recent example of something like this, is the original release of Ubuntu 17.10 which *on some* computers was able to 'break' the BIOS.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/12/ubuntu-corrupting-lenovo-laptop-bios

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-17.10-BIOS-Corrupter

https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-17-10-bios-bug/

Upon the realization that this was actually occuring, Cannonical pulled the suspect version of 17.10, and re-released it as 17.10.1

--  Short answer --

**Yes**, it is possible that an update can cause some damage to your OS or to your computer, damaged being defined as rendering the computer unusable.  *In my experience* this is quite rare and certainly not intentional - I am much more likely to have a damaged computer or operating system due to my own fooling about with the OS and the packages that I have loaded, than I am to suffer damage from an update.

--  The moral of the story --

***Make Backups*** - Often.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your feedback:)  It is wonderful to be able to ask more experienced people and learn from doing so.